# Update field from custom list to second custom list

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list

i have two lists from and i using InfoPath , the first list ("Create Requests from Bulk" ) the second Include information of vendor name and Bulk service that we order from him to use for tasks ("Vendor Bulk) , so the first list the requester insert the data and total amount  , then i made a filed of calculation that show the bulk of second list and make at this field calculation (Bulk-Total Amount)

and my question is how can i take a result of this calculation and update the result at the second list at the field of Bulk after submit

i have been search a lot of information and tried but without success

hope you can help me

Thx

Comment: I would recommend you to use microsoft flow/power automate.

Comment: it will supporting with infopath ?

Answer (score 0):

For a SharePoint list, using flow will be a good option. Add a trigger when an item is created in your first list ("Create Requests from Bulk" ) , then use a update list item/ create a list item(I am not sure which one you will need for second), configure it with information of your second list.

Example: 
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Update-a-secondary-SharePoint-list-using-Flow/ba-p/38201

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-can-I-update-only-1-property-in-a-SharePoint-List/td-p/82047

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to InfoPath form solution then you may create an additional data connection in the second list to update the data or just create a sample workflow in SharePoint designer there you can update list item from one list to another list.

With that being said, you may think to redesign the InfoPath form in powerapps because after 2023 Microsoft will not support InfoPath, hence it is not recommended.